# How can i process the empty strings present in records and get if processed via Spark-Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

Below is the structure of my table.I have a bunch of records present in the below table.

**Products:**

*product_id|product_category_id|product_name|product_descrition|product_price|product_image*

I wanted to sort the data based on product_price, Since it contains null data i am getting the below exception.How can i achieve it in Spark-Scala?

```
val productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products")
productsRDD.map(rec=>rec.split(",")(4).toFloat,rec).sortByKey().take(5).foreach(println)
```

**Exception:**

java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the data instead of filtering it out you can try Try's and Options:

```
import scala.util.Try    

val productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products")
productsRDD.map(rec=> (Try(rec.split(",")(4).toFloat).toOption, rec)).sortByKey().take(5).foreach(println)
```

If you want to set a default value, you can try something like this:

```
import scala.util.Try    

val default = Float.MaxValue
val productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products")
productsRDD.map(rec=> (Try(rec.split(",")(4).toFloat).getOrElse(default), rec)).sortByKey().take(5).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter or filterNot method to filter the empty strings like this :

```
val productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products")
import scala.util.Try  
productsRDD.map{rec=>
val floatValue = Try(rec.split(",")(4).toFloat).toOption
(floatValue,rec)
}.filter(_._1.isDefined).map(a=>(a._1.get,a._2)).sortByKey().take(5).foreach(println)
```

P.s: The code is not tested ! but it should work !

Comment: @eliasah: Nice catch ! , is it now ? ;)

Comment: Is it better but it can be done in a better manner. Actually this assumes that the string is empty if it's not a float which is not correct also

Comment: @eliasah: Now ?

Comment: I'm voting it up for the effort :)

Comment: @Shivnash 'filter(_._1.isDefined)' - Is this required? I am able to achieve it using Try-toOption alone.

Comment: @Raj: I was is defined to filter out the values that were not able to be converted to Float and then next step was getting those values by using get on the Option, and this would work because we have removed all the None values and now , we can apply sorting on Float Value.. 

Now How are you applying sorting without using IsDefined ?

Comment: None is a subclass of Float and have an implicit ordering. `trait OptionOrdering[T] extends Ordering[Option[T]] { def optionOrdering: Ordering[T] def compare(x: Option[T], y: Option[T]) = (x, y) match { case (None, None) => 0 case (None, ) => -1 case (, None) => 1 case (Some(x), Some(y)) => optionOrdering.compare(x, y) } }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using 0 in case of null or calling as instance of:

```
def nullOrFloat(x : String) : Float = x match {
    case x:String  => java.lang.Float.parseFloat(x)
    case null => null.asInstanceOf[Float]
  }

  val productsRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/products")
  productsRDD.map(rec=> ( nullOrFloat(rec.split(",")(4)),rec)).sortByKey().take(5).foreach(println)
```